x86_64 Linear-Address Translation wtih 4-Level paging
As I understand, the 4-level paging uses only the 48 least significant bits.
So, regardless of the other bits, the address will point to the same physical address, correct?
For example:
0xffffffff80101000
0x7fffffff80101000
They will always point to the same physical address, assuming the paging configuration doesn't change, right?
I debug linux kernel use QEMU with GDB, can access 0xffffffff80101000, but 0x7fffffff80101000 always failed.
(gdb) x/1gx 0xffffffff80101000
0xffffffff80101000 <init_level4_pgt>:  0x0000000000102027
(gdb) x/1gx 0x7fffffff80101000
0x7fffffff80101000: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffffff80101000
(gdb)

No, x86-64 requires addressed to be correctly sign-extended (aka in "canonical" form).
